# Have a user close a process' allocated console without exiting the process?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, console, visual-studio-2012

Using the Win32 API in Visual C++, I want to create a program under the Windows subsystem that allocates a console with `AllocConsole` and writes to it with `WriteConsole`. However, if the user closes the console, the process should keep running in the background. As it stands, I can't get that to happen. When X is pressed on the console title bar, the process exits.

Is there any particular way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to respond to the [Console Control Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is raised when the user attempts to close the console. You can then call [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to detach your program from the console, and let the console be destroyed. That *should* keep your program running.

Additional info:

If the process is terminated when the `HandlerRoutine` exits, then my suggestion didn't work as expected. If that's the case, then you might have a problem. You can try hooking the SC_CLOSE system message, and do the `FreeConsole` there before passing the message on. That *might* work, although I don't know what it'll do if the user presses Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break.

The problem is that the control handler exits the process. It might be that calling `FreeConsole` in the `HandlerRoutine` is too late.

Comment: Thanks for this. I created a handler routine, and all's going well. Just one last question: I'm guessing I'll have to do everything else in the scope of the HandlerRoutine function now, because when it returns, the process will automatically exit, right? At least, that's what I'm seeing. (See http://pastebin.com/LHUa3SFh, basic code where the process exits after producing the message box.) Thanks again!

Comment: If I may add to that comment: It may be unnecessary as I could keep the HandlerRoutine on an infinite loop while the main code keeps going...

Comment: @Archimaredes: See my additional info.